# How to update Mapview Periodically?

Tags: iphone, android-mapview

In my application i want to update the MapView periodically and redraw the the path on map as per new location.
Is it possible using MKMapView?

This is my didload metho for drawing and annotation on mapview.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {

NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"xxxxx.php?uid=%@&buddy_uid=%@",UserUID,buddyUid];
NSLog(@"%@",url);
NSLog(@"%@",url);
NSString * jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"return data %@",jsonString);
NSDictionary *jsonDic = [jsonString JSONValue];
buddyLocation = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@,%@",[jsonDic objectForKey:@"Lattitude"],[jsonDic objectForKey:@"Longitude"]];

[super viewDidLoad];

locmanager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; 
[locmanager setDelegate:self]; 
[locmanager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
//[locmanager startUpdatingLocation];
MKMapView *mapnew;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    mapnew = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004)];
}
else
{
    mapnew = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
}

[mapnew setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:mapnew];

MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } }; 
region.center.latitude = lat1 floatValue];//22.56574;
region.center.longitude =lng1 floatValue];//73.74575;
NSString *currentLocation = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@,%@",lat1,lng1];
NSLog(@"%@",currentLocation);

DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init]; 
ann.title = @"Current Location";
ann.coordinate = region.center; 
[mapnew addAnnotation:ann];

NSLog(@"%@",jsonDic);
region.center.latitude = [[jsonDic objectForKey:@"Lattitude"] floatValue];//23.56574;
region.center.longitude = [[jsonDic objectForKey:@"Longitude"] floatValue];//72.74575;

ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init]; 
ann.title = @"Buddy Location";
ann.coordinate = region.center; 

    [mapnew addAnnotation:ann];
    KMLParser *kml = [KMLParser parseKMLAtURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString 
    stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%@&daddr=%@&
    output=kml",currentLocation,buddyLocation]]]; 
    NSArray *overlays = [kml overlays];
    [mapnew addOverlays:overlays];

    MKMapRect flyTo = MKMapRectNull;
    for (id <MKOverlay> overlay in overlays) 
    {
        if (MKMapRectIsNull(flyTo)) 
        {
            flyTo = [overlay boundingMapRect];
        }
        else 
        {
            flyTo = MKMapRectUnion(flyTo, [overlay boundingMapRect]);
        }
    }

    mapnew.visibleMapRect = flyTo;
    [mapnew release];
    mapnew =nil;
}

 }
 -(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay 
 {        
MKPolylineView *line = [[[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay] autorelease]; 
line.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor]; 
line.lineWidth =2.0;
return line;
 }
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you want to do. You should expand your question and add some examples.

Comment: I want to track the person who is on my list.
In Mapview i am showing the path and pin between my current location to friend's location.
So it is drawing for only first time when i load the view.
But i want to update path on MapView at specific time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewDidiLoad method is called only once when the view is loaded After that it would only give control to methods like viewWillappear etc on successive visits . What you have to do is seperate the method which parses the  location data from viewDidLoad, and make it set an array or objects . And call the method to reset these contents on Map i.e. remove previous annotations or overlay and then add new ones . problem solved. You could call these method at fixed interval using timer or something like that. I guess this should help.

Comment: Probably best to tie it in to receiving a location update, either in a MKMapView or CLLocation delegate method, and check for the location to have changed from the previous location by a significant amount.

Comment: yes that would help only if he is checking only users location. He also wants to monitor friends

Comment: Well, he does refer to his "current location", which should be being updated.  It isn't clear if the php call is finding his friend's location; if it is, then yes, call that on a timer.  But the location updates should be tracked as well.